# reading entries from database

Tags: php, html, pdo

is anyone able to find out what went wrong in this code below? It just shows a blank page. I'm new to PDO, always used mysqli but someone told me to try PDO since my page had problems showing arabic characters.

```
    <html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;charset=UTF8;' 
$user = 'dbuser'; // don't hardcode this...store it elsewhere
$password = 'dbpass'; // this too...

try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT :column FROM :table";
$opts = array(
  ':column' => 'Name',
  ':table' => 'Mothakirat'
);
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if ($statement->execute($opts)) {
  $resultArray = array();     // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
  $tempArray = array();           // to hold the data

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) // Loop through each row in the result set    
  {
    $tempArray = $row;    // Add each row into our results array
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
  }
  echo json_encode($resultArray);     // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
}
$dbh->commit();
</html>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting, at the top of the page: error_reporting(E_ALL); Then post back with any errors you are not sure about.

Comment: nothing shows up still @Chris

Comment: You should also tell PDO to throw exceptions so that it will tell you what went wrong in case it is related to the database. Add this as a 4th parameter to your `new PDO()` call: `array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: And you have a typo on line 5, you forgot the `;` at the end...

Comment: Then add try/catch block around the execution, start it before beginTransaction line and end it after commit line, otherwise you wont pick up the exception, you have only put the connection into one.

Comment: Final note.. your getting a parse error.. you have no closing ?> before the </html> tag, i actually suspect that will fix your problem.

Comment: @Chris That's not necessary, if you don't do that you will get an `unhandled exception error` that results in more information than with a *regular* `try - catch` block.

Comment: done but did not fix anything. @jeroen

Comment: @Chris fixed but nothing. I'm really starting to hate PDO.

Comment: You're not displaying errors so you will not see them. Put this at the top `ini_set('display_errors',0);` and get a decent IDE so that you will catch these simple typos.

Comment: there is a semi colon missing after your dsn

Comment: And if you don't like PDO, don't use it. Note that it will not solve your character set problems as mysqli is just as capable in displaying them as PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has no parse errors checked in my IDE. I use netbeans, its very good and available on several platforms.

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php

/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;charset=UTF8;';
$user = 'dbuser'; // don't hardcode this...store it elsewhere
$password = 'dbpass'; // this too...

try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT :column FROM :table";
$opts = array(
  ':column' => 'Name',
  ':table' => 'Mothakirat'
);
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if ($statement->execute($opts)) {
  $resultArray = array();     // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
  $tempArray = array();           // to hold the data

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) // Loop through each row in the result set    
  {
    $tempArray = $row;    // Add each row into our results array
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
  }
  echo json_encode($resultArray);     // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
}
$dbh->commit();
?>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree. Next problem: Outputted json is not valid ;-)

Comment: @Sam You are outputting html as well, so the end result will not be valid json. If you need that of course...

Comment: They are correct, if you need json then you need to move this to a function/class and return, if its just for testing as it appears this will be just fine to give you a visual of the json result.